# How to navigate this track?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given a track with no walls/boundaries what is the best way to navigate it? There are no color differences b/w what we can drive on and what we can't. Just a white line. What is the best ROS Package for this kind of navigation and are there any examples? We have a 2d lidar and a stereo camera if it helps

Track example:
[image: image description]

Our track is bigger, wider and more one dimensional in routes but the challenge is the same

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366942/how-to-navigate-this-track?/) by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a form of lane detection and following would help a lot to be able to maintain the robot on the path.
You can try playing around with the turtlebot autorace package, has a lot of interesting things and can help you learn!

You can try following this tutorial: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/
and the code you can find here: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_autorace_2020

---

Originally posted by [ingenious_doc](https://answers.ros.org/users/71533/ingenious_doc/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on 2021-04-19**:
Thanks for the links!